# calculating expected number of free games in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

On average every 70 games the player will play 10 free game (unpaid games) and during the free games the player will have the same $\frac{1}{70}$ chance of 10 more free games. What is the expected number of free games the player will get?

Now, to solve this problem i had in my mind the binomial distribution. Since the first line talks about the average, so i used the formula $np=mean$ and used $p=\frac{1}{70}$. This calculated the value of $n$. or the total games in my opinion. But, i cannot think of anything else in this problem. Because the latter part of the problem also talks about the expected number. Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Assuming that you pay for $70$ games (only), it looks like you **first** get $(1 \times 10)$ free games.  Then, taking $p = \displaystyle \frac{1}{70},$ you then get another $(p \times 10)$ free games.  Then, you get another $(p^2 \times 10)$ free games, and so forth.  Unsure if I have correctly interpreted the problem composer's intent.  This is simply how the problem strikes me.

Comment: So, to find the total number of games, i should add them all. That means total number of games are approximately 10. Is it ok to say approximately?

Comment: $\displaystyle p = \frac{1}{70}.$  Let $F$ denote the total number of free games.  Assume that you pay for exactly $70$ games (and no more).  Then, **if** I have interpreted the problem composer's intent accurately, $$F = 10 \times \left(1 + p + p^2 + \cdots \right) = 10 \times \left[\frac{1}{1-p}\right].$$  This implies that $$F = 10 \times \left[\frac{70}{69}\right].$$